# Where EXISTS slowing down query

Tags: mysql

This query takes many time.
I use index to `model_id`, `model_type` fields.

When I run separate each other this two queries they are super fast.
How can I optimize this query?

I have 350k rows in `posts` and 270k rows in `media`.

Query:

```
SELECT
    Count(`*`) AS aggregate
FROM
    `posts`
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            media
        WHERE
            posts.id = media.model_id
            AND media.model_type = 'App\Models\Post')
```

Execute: 1.23s

Comment: Include `SHOW CREATE TABLE media`, `SHOW CREATE TABLE Posts`, `EXPLAIN {query}` and your mysql version in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First filter the rows of the table `media`, then join to `posts` and count:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS aggregate
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT model_id
  FROM media
  WHERE model_type = 'App\Models\Post'
) m ON m.model_id = p.id
```

Depending on your data you could use `COUNT(DISTINCT p.id)` instead of `COUNT(*)`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try an normal join instead

```
select count(p.id)
from posts p
join media m on p.id = m.model_id
where m.model_type = 'App\Models\Post'
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on one assumption that every `media` has one post and not many, your query could be simplified to:

```
select count(distinct model_id)
from media
where model_type = 'App\Models\Post'
```

to perform this efficiently a combined `model_type`,`model_id` index like below will help if one doesn't exists:

```
ALTER TABLE media ADD INDEX model_type_id(model_type, model_id);
```